# MSO2-expressible graph properties unexpressible in MSO1

Tags: graph-theory, lo.logic

I would like to ask if there is any good list of graph properties that one can express in the MSO2 (i.e., using quantification over sets of edges) but provably not in MSO1 (i.e., using quantification over sets of vertices only). I know that this should be *Hamilton path* but I think that there has to be plenty such examples. Ideal are those that are suitable as exercises for non-expressibility results using Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games.

Answer (score 4):

Nice question.  I am also keen to learn of more examples.

Here are some more details on the Hamiltonian cycle example.  This is expressible in $\mathsf{MSO_2}$ since testing if a graph is connected is expressible in $\mathsf{MSO}_2$ and testing if a set of edges induces a $2$-regular subgraph is clearly expressible in $\mathsf{MSO}_2$.  Indeed, connectivity is actually expressible in $\mathsf{MSO_1}$ since a graph $G$ is connected if and only if for all partitions $A \cup B$ of $V(G)$ there is an edge between $A$ and $B$.  However, $\mathsf{MSO}_1$ does not know the difference between balanced complete bipartite graphs (which do have Hamiltonian cycles) and unbalanced complete bipartite graphs (which do not have Hamiltonian cycles).

**Edit**.  Another example I thought that works is the existence of an odd (or even) length path between two fixed vertices $u$ and $v$.  However, this turns out to be expressible in both $\mathsf{MSO}_2$ and $\mathsf{MSO}_1$. Thanks to Emil Jeřábek for the comments below.

Odd length paths are expressible in $\mathsf{MSO}_2$ since a path between $u$ and $v$ is a set of edges $P$ such that $G[P]$ is connected, $u$ and $v$ have degree $1$ in $G[P]$ and all other vertices in $G[P]$ have degree $2$.  We can say that $P$ has odd length in $\mathsf{MSO}_2$ since $P$ has odd length (*length* is the number of edges) if and only if there exists a partition $A \cup B$ of $V(P)$ such that $u \in A$, $v \in B$, and for each $e \in P$, $e$ has one end in $A$ and one end in $B$.

For $\mathsf{MSO}_1$, we can say that $u$ and $v$ are connected by an odd length path in $G$ if there exist disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of $V(G)$ such that $u \in A$, $v \in B$, and the subgraph consisting of all edges between $A$ and $B$ is connected.

Comment: I would only add to your example with path that for the set P the graph G[P] must be connected as otherwise it is possible to cheat using disconnected cycles. But this is only minor correction.

Comment: I may be missing something, but there is an even-length path between $u$ and $v$ in $G$  iff there is a path between $u$ and $v$ in $G^2$, and the latter is FO definable in $G$, which should give an $\mathrm{MSO}_1$ expression. The case of odd-length paths is similar.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek If by $G^2$ you mean the graph with the same vertex set as $G$ and where $u$ and $v$ are adjacent in $G^2$ if they are at distance at most $2$ from each other in $G$, then the iff does not hold.  For example, $G$ is a subgraph of $G^2$.  Putting edges if the vertices are at distance exactly $2$ will not work either.  For example, consider the complete graphs.

Comment: Never mind, I think I need more coffee.

Comment: Yes, I want the path to be simple, but you did get me thinking.  It seems like the partition formula might work in $\mathsf{MSO}_1$. If we consider a shortest length odd path, then the formula is something like there are disjoint subsets $A,B$ such that $u \in A, v \in B$, $u$ is adjacent to exactly one vertex in $B$, $v$ is adjacent to exactly one vertex in $A$, each vertex in $A$ (other than $u$) is adjacent to exactly two vertices in $B$, and each vertex in $B$ (other than $v$) is adjacent to exactly two vertices in $A$.

Comment: Yes, I think that should work. I have meanwhile had the coffee, and figured the following alternative way: there is an even-length path from $u$ to $v$ iff there is a partition of $V(G)$ in two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ such that $u,v\in A$, and there is a walk from $u$ to $v$ alternating between $A$ and $B$; the latter amounts to the connectivity of $u$ and $v$ in the graph $H$ with $V(H)=A$, and $\{x,y\}\in E(H)$ iff $\exists z\in B\,(\{x,z\},\{y,z\}\in E(G))$. (Odd-length paths are similar.) This is expressible in $\mathrm{MSO}_1$.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a book available online which gives some answers to your question. The book is [Graph Structure and Monadic Second-Order Logic: a Language Theoretic Approach](http://www.labri.fr/perso/courcell/Book/TheBook.pdf) by Courcelle and Engelfriet. I am not (at all) an expert on this topic, but the book seems like a good reference. It lists the existence of a Hamiltonian cycle as an example. Some additional interesting examples included in the book are:

- If a graph is simple
- Existence of a perfect matching
- Existence of a spanning tree with maximum degree 3

The most relevant parts of the book are Proposition 5.13, Proposition 5.19, and Remark 5.21. Showing the existence of a perfect matching is not expressible in $MSO_1$ can be with the same arguement on complete bipartite graphs $K_{n,m}$ outlined in Tony Huynh's answer. Also, it seems to me the example of a spanning tree with maximum degree 3 in Remark 5.21 can be modified to show that the existence of a spanning tree with maximum degree $k$ for some given $k$ in not expressible in $MSO_1$ (put more "leaves" on the graph in Figure 5.3).